# Set top left image on dialog pane with javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I need to set my image in the top left corner of my desktop. I tried various options but I didn't find the satisfactory one. I put my code and the related screen:

```
public void deleteUser() {
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    alert.setTitle("Confirmation Removal");
    alert.setHeaderText("EC-18 removal user");
    alert.setContentText("Are you sure to delete " + user.getName() + " " + user.getSurname() + "?");
    Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
    if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
        databaseConnection.delete("utenti/" + user.getUserId());
        ((Stage)label_name.getScene().getWindow()).close();
    } else {
        ((Stage)label_name.getScene().getWindow()).close();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: From some quick, non-exhaustive testing using JavaFX 13 and Windows 10 it appears a dialog window will inherit the icon(s) of its owner window. However, you can also use `(Stage) dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow()` so you can add your icon. I don't believe there's any guarantee in the documentation that a dialog will use a `Stage` internally, however.

Comment: @Slaw while not documented, a [fixed bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8093842) seems to indicate design intention to let a dialog always have the same icon as its window owner. Couldn't find anything regarding the default window being a stage always - the accepted answer of the duplicate shows how to enforce that.

Answer (score 0):

The Class that loads first when your application runs is the best place to set the little bmp image we keep it at a 32 by 32 size and we make our own with GreenFish Editor do a search it is FREE
Welcome to Stack Overflow

```
public class Start extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("start.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("checkbook.css").toExternalForm());
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.getIcons().add(new Image("Images/C.bmp"));// All Stages have this icon
    stage.setTitle("Check Book");
```

Comment: as is, it's not really related to the question: doesn't help to set the _dialog_ icon - you must also set the stage with the custom icon as the dialog's owner.